# layout_gravity of button in LinearLayout not working correctly

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, layout-gravity

My requirement is to achieve this in LinearLayout. It is having only one child view.
In horizontal orientation, a button needs to be at center horizontal, if layout_gravity is set. 
my layout xml is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:background="#ffff00"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But the result is like below image

[image]

What i am expecting is, when the layout_gravity is set to center_horizontal , the button center to the horizontal. Why this is not working

Comment: android:layout_gravity="center" use only center and orientation to vertical

Comment: @Brendon can you post link to the documentation describing this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with yours is not with your actual element but with your parent element. When you define the same property to the parent element, your issue will be resolved.

add the following attribute to the `LinearLayout`

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it in two Method,

Set **android:gravity="center_horizontal"** in layout properties

or

Set **android:layout_gravity="center"** in Button properties

Your Layout to be in "Vertical" Orientation

Answer (score 1):

We need to figure out the question is:

- The widget can only use **vertical attribute** (like `top`, `center_vertical`, `bottom`)  when it's root layout use`orientation: horizontal`
- The widget can only use **horizontal attribute** (like `left`, `center_horizontal`, `right`)  when it's root layout use `orientation: vertical`

So that you need to do like this(tested & works):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#ffff00"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[Test Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJESQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Set center horizontal gravity to the parent:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#ffff00"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

or just change parent orientation to `horizontal`

Comment: any other way to achieve this in child level.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cant. Your root layout is horizontal orientationL `android:orientation="horizontal"`. If you want it work, just change root's orientation to `vertical` (I dont test yet!)